# Finding $\cos(A) + \cos(2A) = 0$ on $(0; \pi)$

Tags: trigonometry

How to prove that $\cos(A) + \cos(2A) = 0$ only for $A = \frac{\pi}{3}$ for $A \in (0; \pi)$?

Comment: Suggestion: Try rewriting $\cos(2A)$ as $2cos^2(A)-1$ by the double angle formula, and now you have a quadratic equation you can solve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\cos A+\cos 2A=2\cos^2 A +\cos A-1=0$, so $\cos A=1/2$ or $-1$. Since $A \in (0,\pi), A=\pi/3$